# Angle of fishing rod holder for dock

Tags: fishing, fishing-rods

I want to make a fishing rod holder to hold my fishing rod while I'm sitting at a cottage dock. I'll be fishing for bass with a worm, a large red/white bobber, and a large hook (Ontario).

I've noticed most fishing rod holders are designed so that the rod is angled. Do I need an angle for this kind of fishing? What's the purpose of the angle?

Or is there not much benefit, and I could simply stick the rod in the end of the 2-inch square aluminum post, making the rod vertical?

---

Example of a [store-bought holder](https://dockessentials.com/products/fishing-rod-holder-2-0):

[image]

Dock photos:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wod7.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLVsf.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually those are ~45 degree angle 'cause if it was just straight up - your line would be flapping too close to the dock and usually you want to reach out a bit.
On other hand if it was angled completely parallel to the water - any big fish taking a bit would have a chance to simply tear your rod from the holder. You can make it anywhere from 60 to 30 degrees in my opinion, up to preference.

Also make sure that you're getting a nice metal ones, I've had polymer ones on a rented boat once and they tend to bend/crack under pressure